# What causes the following error message, "friend declaration of 'ConnectHandler' does not match any declaration in namespace 'Crafter'"?

Tags: c++, g++, clang++, libcrafter

I was working on a project that links to libcrafter (Version 0.2), today. When I build this project with g++ (5.4), there were no problems.

I'm working on switching to clang-8, so I set CC and CXX to clang, clang++ respectively, ran a cmake, and started the build over.

That resulted in the titular error message:

```
friend declaration of 'ConnectHandler' does not match any declaration in the namespace 'Crafter'
/* Rest of the error message, including the following declaration
 * friend void* Crafter::ConnectHandler(void *thread_arg), the line and
 * column number, filename etc.
 */
```

I also got the same error for another function in the code. The errors were indicated in crafter/Utils/TCPConnection.h (line 247, 248).

On checking the header file, I found the friend declarations:

```
namespace Crafter
{
    class TCPBuffer
    {
        // Stuff
    };

    class TCPConnection
    {
        // Other declarations etc.
        friend void* Crafter::ConnectHandler(void *thread_arg);
        friend void Crafter::PckHand(Crafter::Packet *sniff_packet, void *user);
        // Class declaration continues
    };
}
```

And in the TCPConnection.cpp file, I found:

```
namespace Crafter
{
    void* ConnectHandler(void *thread_arg);
    void PckHand(Packet *sniff_packet, void *user);
}

// Intervening code

void Crafter::PckHand(Crafter::Packet *sniff_packet, void *user
{
    // Do stuff
}

void* Crafter::ConnectHandler(void *thread_arg)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

This looked okay to me, and my g++ based build offered no complaints. I tried to reproduce this with a minimal working example, but I have been unable to succeed so far: compiles without errors.

An added note is that this error turned up not while building crafter itself, but while building another piece of code that links to it. Specifically, `filename.cc` had the TCPConnection.h file included from my project includes directory, and that's where the compiler pointed me.

I would greatly appreciate any help in understanding this error, and resolving it.

Comment: Put your function body in the namespace, to begin with, then why has `PckHand` first argument another `Crafter`?

Comment: @Matthieu Brucher, good point. Crafter is a third party lib, but I couldn't copy paste. I typed the entire thing in by hand, and made a mistake. Fixing now.